# Reanimated2: Transform with key of "rotate" must be a string

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-reanimated

I am using Reanimated2 on my React Native app in an Android emulator. I am trying to rotate a component using `useAnimatedStyle`. Here's my code. It works on iOS, but on Android I get an error.

```
const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    let rotate = interpolate(x.value, [-150, 0, 150], [-Math.PI / 36, 0, Math.PI / 36], Extrapolate.CLAMP);
    return {
      transform: [{ translateY: y.value }, { translateX: x.value }, { rotate }],
    }
  });
```

I'm getting the following error on Android only: `Transform with key of "rotate" must be a string: {"rotate":0}]`

Then I change the code to a string:

```
const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    let rotate = interpolate(x.value, [-150, 0, 150], ["-10deg", "0deg", "10deg"], Extrapolate.CLAMP);
    return {
      transform: [{ translateY: y.value }, { translateX: x.value }, { rotate }],
    }
  });
```

Then I get this error:

```
Error while updating property 'transform' of a view managed by: RTCView

null

For input string: "-10degNaN"
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/1.x.x/nodes/interpolate/

The documentation states, that you should use your first approach. Interpolate the numbers and then add the `deg` afterwards.

This should do the trick:

```
const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    let rotate = interpolate(x.value, [-150, 0, 150], [-Math.PI / 36, 0, Math.PI / 36], Extrapolate.CLAMP);
    return {
      transform: [{ translateY: y.value }, { translateX: x.value }, { rotate: `${rotate}deg` }],
    }
  });
```